# how to make whole menu bar item area clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

i 'm working with menu bar control. here is my css and design code:

css :

```
.Menu 
{ 
    background:transparent url(../images/blueslate_background.gif) repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
    font-family : "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: None 0px #fff !important;
}

.menuhover
{
     color:#fff;
     background:transparent url(../images/blueslate_backgroundOVER.gif) repeat-x left center;
     cursor:pointer;
}
```

design :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MenuControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MenuControl" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Menu3.css" type="text/css" />
<div id="header" align="center" >
<table width="100%" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
   <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation ="Horizontal"  CssClass="Menu"
        ForeColor ="Black" Width="100%" ScrollDownText="">
     <StaticMenuItemStyle Height ="40px"/>
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass ="Menu" Height="30px" HorizontalPadding="10px"/>
    <dynamichoverstyle  CssClass ="menuhover"/>
    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass ="menuhover"/>
    </asp:Menu>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

i just want to make whole menu bar list item area clickable is it possible with jquery or javascript.

**------------------------------------Updated-----------------------------------------------------**

here is some example to make whole div clickable with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                 
     $(".thumb").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");return false;
     });
});
</script>
```

**------------------------------------Updated-----------------------------------------------------**

solution :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                 
     $(".Menu").click(function(e) {
         window.location = $(e.target).find("a").attr("href");
         return false;
     });
});
</script>
```

Error occurs when i clicks original Menu Text
Error:

```
Server Error in '/EasyWeb' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /EasyWeb/undefined

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

Comment: can you provide rendered code link?

Comment: you should provide in question rendered HTML code, not server side code to generate HTML. BTW, you could set a sample on jsfiddle.

Comment: It looks as if you're using a table for layout of your menu. Tables should really only be used to present tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to check if "header" is clicked and then check what element has been clicked..

In this case you have to check, with JQuery for instance:

```
$('#header').on('click', function(e) {
    var what = $(e.target).html();
    $('#clicked').html("You have selected: " + what);
});
```

Take a look on this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypc2T/).
Or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ypc2T/1/), more nice.

## Edit

To check also href in a element, take a look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypc2T/2/).

## Edit2

```
$(document).ready(function() {                 
     $(".Menu").click(function(e) {
         window.location = $(e.target).find("a").attr("href");
         return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: here i just want to make  window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");return false;

Comment: i have menu bar that have multiple items with it's which all have Navigation Url to redirect to some page. and all items i think rendered as anchor tag.

Comment: just see my updated question and figure out what i want to do with whole menu list item area should be clickable.

Comment: ya i just updated my question can u resolve my problem.

Comment: method $(this).find(a) --> returns first a in clicked div. I edited answer

Comment: i found one bug when i click Menu Text area then it's give me one exception. please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a click handler for the elements with the .Menu class.

```
$(document).on("click", ".Menu", function(){
  alert("Menu clicked");
})
```